# Call Click Event of other activity from one activity in android

Tags: android, buttonclick

I want to call the click event of specific button of other activity from my new activity. Is it a possible in android and if yes then how can I achieve the same.

Comment: You could extract the code inside the clickevent of your button in a method and call this method instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the code of that button's click event is not open for me, I had added this Activity by adding a JAR file as library, so i cant see the code of that button.

Comment: Then try `button.performClick()`

Comment: Use     BroadcastReceiver for the purpose

Answer (score 0):

You could implement and interface in the one activity and call it in the second activity.